# In despair, how to route a React app with Next.js

Tags: reactjs, routes, next.js, browser, frontend

I am new to Next.js. I have my index.js in the Pages folder and 3 other files in a component folder under Pages. In that folder, I have a Signup.js, Signin.js and a Lostpassword.js. What I am trying to do is have the index page open to Signup.js and then be able to click the Sign IN link and be redirected to SignIn.js and same with Lostpassword.js and the appropriate link.

I know Next.js does SSR and I think my issue is I'm not grasping the concept behind client-side rendering or something. I need guidance on how to integrate a full React component within a next.js environment.

I've been searching the web for solutions, but it's hard to find anything when you aren't sure what you're looking for.

I'm able to get the index page to open SignIn.js but the navigating "within the component" is broken and I keep getting 404 errors.

I've tried using  but keep getting errors with document because it rendered server side. So, I tried using  but that didn't work either. I tried modifying the paths and putting everything below Pages but no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Next.js uses a concept called [server-centric routing](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing#server-centric-routing-with-client-side-navigation), another term for this is file-system based router. You can learn about routing in a Next.js project in their [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing).

In Next.js you can route the user using the `link` component ([read more](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/linking-and-navigating#the-link-component)) which is similar in concept to the `a` tag in vanilla HTML. Or you can use `useRouter`([read more](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router)) from `next/router` which behaves similarly to `useHistory` from `react-router`.

To achieve the result you are describing I think you have two main choices.

1. You can dynamically render the components within `index.js` based on the authentication status/user actions.
2. You can route the users to the appropriate page based on their authentication status (I would recommend this approach).

As a pseudocode example of the second option you would have a file structure similar to this in your pages folder. With a file-system based router the page names correspond to the route paths:

```
├── index.js (example.com)
├── sign-in.js (example.com/sign-in)
├── sign-up.js (example.com/sign-up)
├── forgot-password.js (example.com/forgot-password)
└── foo
    ├── index.js (example.com/foo)
    └── bar.js (example.com/foo/bar)
```

in your `index.js`

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

//...

// route user based on authentication status
if(user is authenticated) {
   router.push("/foo/bar");
}
else if (user is not authenticated) {
   router.push("/sign-in");
}
```

in your `sign-in.js`

```
import Link from 'next/link';

//...

<Link className="button" href="/forgot-password">Forgot Password</Link>
```